# Update Javascript event listeners after AJAX adds new elements

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have search the forums here, but still could not find the right answer.
I see solutions with jQuery which I am not familiar with. I am looking for vanilla JavaScript solution please.
In short, I create elements dynamically with Ajax and I need to add event listeners to them once they are created. The js here privides suggestions when a user starts typing in input boxes. The code works fine if the input is static, but does not with dynamic. I know DOM gets constructed on load and those elements do not exist yet at the time of loading.

Main page:

```
<head>

  <script src="../js/autocomplete-type.js"></script>

   <script>
     window.addEventListener("load", function(){
       suggest.attach({
         target : "NCustType",
         url : "../private/searchdbtype.php",
         data : { type: "CustType" }
       });
     })
  </script>
</head>
```

autocomplete-type.js is pretty long, so not sure if I should post it here.

body on load:

```
<table id='CustDetails'></table>
```

Ajax fills this table with the following innerHTML (posting here just one element):

```
<tr>
  <td>Customer Type</td>
  <td><input type='text' id='NCustType'></td>
</tr>
```

So I need to add an event listener with function "suggest" with attachments {} to input box with id='NCustType'. I will appreciate help with JavaScript suggestions! I am not a pro with coding but this issue drives me crazy. And I would like to avoid jQuery please.

This part of the code (in automcomplete-type.js) adds a listener:

`suggest.instance[opt.target].input.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
      // Clear old timer
      if (suggest.instance[opt.target].timer != null) {
        window.clearTimeout(suggest.instance[opt.target].timer);
      }`
However, the file is generic and is used for different fields

So how do I call that js file AND function in 'head' (with parameters) after Ajax fires?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: So what adds the table? Call a function that binds the autosuggest when that completes.

Comment: Epascarello, multiple rows/columns are added to the table with multiple input fields. This table is dynamic. Ajax sends request to another php page which constructs that table and fills out inputs. However, then lets say I need to edit the field but my suggestion function does not work

Comment: Teshnizi, the above mentioned link suggests jQuery and I am looking for vanilla js solution

Comment: The question linked has answers which do not use jQuery; [this one, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/215552).

Comment: Heretic, it is based on classes, I have dozens of fields so I need to use ids plus that post does not explain much in details

Comment: I tried to wrap all autocomplete js code in one function in js file, then use AppendChild method step by step. Inserted this code after Ajax inserted html. Still not working:

`<script>var node = document.getElementById('newrow');
document.getElementById('CustDetails').appendChild(node);
var node2 = document.getElementById('newcolumn');
node.appendChild(node2);
var node3 = document.getElementById('NCustType');
node2.appendChild(node3);
callsuggest();</script>`

Comment: FYI, to reply to someone, put an @ symbol in front of their name, like @MaxCB.

Comment: @MaxCB if you remember, how you solved this, can please add your own answer with that? Might be useful, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add event listener to elements, which do not exist yet, there is a trick: you attach event listener to the `document` and then rely on event "bubbling" up from the element through the DOM tree.

In code that would look like

```
// Attach event listener to the document
document.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    // Make sure, that you're receiving event from a correct element
    if (event.target.id === 'NCustType') {
        // Do what you want to do here
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: problem here is wants to add the autosuggest code, not listen to change.

Comment: then maybe he can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect the ajax added elements and act upon them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, the html elements do not exist before doing the ajax request, which means that you can only do the event bindings afterwards. So after doing the ajax call, you need to iterate every result and create a listener for each id input that you're creating.

```
fetch('my/api').then(r => {
   r.map(item => {
    document.querySelector(`#${item.id}-input`).addEventListener('keyup', yourfunction);
   })
})
```

Comment: Hi, if `item` means an html element, then isn't it too expensive to call `document.querySelector` on each iteration (of the map)? Can't be just call `querySelector` on the actual `item` itself somehow?

Comment: i mean: can't just target the actual `item` more directly without `querySelector` somehow ? (i don't know how `item` looks like, so just theory)

Comment: just a minor thing, about performance but, here can be used `getElementById` (if there is no more direct way) instead of `querySelector` [this article](https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/) says, it's 2x faster. If your table would have many thousands of rows to modify, it might start to count ;)